# Programmatically run specific TestNG method with virtual xml

Tags: java, xml, testng

I have this code to generate a virtual TestNG XML file, and it successfully programmatically runs the specified class:

```
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("TmpSuite");

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("TmpTest");
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("browser", "Firefox");
    suite.setParameters(parameters);

    classes.add(new XmlClass(classToBeRun));
    test.setXmlClasses(classes);


    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
```

However, I want to be able to execute a specific method from within that class (instead of every method in the class). How can I do that? I already have the logic in place to extract the test methods and choose the specific one, I just need to be able to specify it in that virtual XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried these two methods - [setExcludedMethods](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/xml/XmlClass.html#setExcludedMethods(java.util.List)) and [setIncludedMethods](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/xml/XmlClass.html#setIncludedMethods(java.util.List)). Looks like you can achieve what you want using these.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using testng [method groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#method-groups). 
Basically you have to generate the following:

```
<test name="TmpTest"> 
  <classes> 
    <class name="example1.MyTest"> 
      <methods> 
        <include name=".*enabledTestMethod.*"/> 
        <exclude name=".*brokenTestMethod.*"/> 
      </methods>
     </class> 
  </classes> 
</test>
```